# using an external .rb in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a separate .rb file that contains smth like this:

```
if lang == 'fr'
    @a = 'AAAAAAA'
    @b = 'BBBBBBB'
    @c = 'CCCCCCC'
else
    @a = 'sadadddsad'
    @b = 'dsafdsfdasfdsa'
    @c = 'dsadasfdsfsfd'
end
```

, only with a lot more strings.

Being a large library of strings, and wanting to keep this in one place as these will be used in multiple controllers and functions within, what is a good method to call these files from inside a function in controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to use **Internationalization** in your app. You could follow this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html to know more and its implementation.

Comment: Thank you .It seems to be just what I need.